# Can Excel VBA listen for Javascript events in acrobat?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, dom-events, acrobat

I have a project in which I use Excel VBA to operate on a global variable which is defined (and frequently changed) in Acrobat Javascript.

All of the individual routines and functions in this project work as intended, but I am having some trouble with my event handling.

Basically, I need to execute a VBA routine whenever the value of the JS global variable is changed. I can do this now using a time loop in VBA (wait x seconds, test if the `jso.global.variable` has changed, execute code if true, test again in x seconds if false), but this seems clumsy and slow.

**Is it possible to do the same thing more quickly and efficiently using some sort of native event handler in either VBA or JS?**

(Alternatively, *I could also solve my issue if I could somehow call a VBA routine from Acrobat JS directly, but it does not appear that this is possible -- please correct me if this is wrong.*)

Comment: You can use Application.OnTime to set events in VBA. It is better than doing a loop, but it is still 'polling' more or less since you have to check if your variable changes and set the event again each time. EG: Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "my_Procedure" .

From my understanding, Acrobat's javascript is just a 'sandbox'. So you can't open and maintain Excel objects through Javascript. Even if maintain the Acrobat Javascript within excel... AFAIK Excel VBA only handles its own internal events (Ribbon, Worksheet Changes, etc).

Comment: @KrisB Thank you, I'll look into the OnTime command. :)

Comment: I see that Acrobat as a (perhaps limited) postMessage function. So far it hasnt been clear to me if/how I might be able to use that to do what I need to do. It appears that Acrobat JS can only post messages to "this.hostContainer" but it doesn't look like I am able to set things up in such a way that Acrobat recognizes Excel (or an excel userform and webbrowser) as the document's hostContainer. It seems to me like what I am trying to do ought to be easier than it has been so far, but obviously that doesn't always mean that it actually is easier. ;)